# Event Based POI reading Excel with hidden columns

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, sax

I downloaded an excel file which has a hidden column (first column (A1)) along with other column values which are visible to the user.  But when I am trying to read this excel using SAX event POI, it never processes the excel file. In startelement method, we do a check  `if(name.equals("c")) {  ......}` but this condition is never met when the excel file had a hidden column(The first column).

However when I make the hidden column visible, it reads(processes) the excel file.  Another observation made is, once you make the hidden column visible and hide the column again, the excel file is read.

Please suggest.

Comment: What is the question that you are asking?

Comment: Great observation... Thanks for your information...

Comment: The parser should read the hidden columns in excel which is not happening currently

Answer (score 1):

Try the code [here](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api)

I did it with an xlsx with a hidden column and the same xlsx with the column unhidden and both revealed all of the columns of the spreadsheet including cells in hidden columns.  A bit long is the code, but I put it anyway in the event the link dies someday.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFReader;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory;

public class ExampleEventUserModel {
    public void processOneSheet(String filename) throws Exception {
        OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(filename);
        XSSFReader r = new XSSFReader( pkg );
        SharedStringsTable sst = r.getSharedStringsTable();

        XMLReader parser = fetchSheetParser(sst);

        // rId2 found by processing the Workbook
        // Seems to either be rId# or rSheet#
        InputStream sheet2 = r.getSheet("rId2");
        InputSource sheetSource = new InputSource(sheet2);
        parser.parse(sheetSource);
        sheet2.close();
    }

    public void processAllSheets(String filename) throws Exception {
        OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(filename);
        XSSFReader r = new XSSFReader( pkg );
        SharedStringsTable sst = r.getSharedStringsTable();

        XMLReader parser = fetchSheetParser(sst);

        Iterator<InputStream> sheets = r.getSheetsData();
        while(sheets.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("Processing new sheet:\n");
            InputStream sheet = sheets.next();
            InputSource sheetSource = new InputSource(sheet);
            parser.parse(sheetSource);
            sheet.close();
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    public XMLReader fetchSheetParser(SharedStringsTable sst) throws SAXException {
        XMLReader parser =
            XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader(
                    "org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser"
            );
        ContentHandler handler = new SheetHandler(sst);
        parser.setContentHandler(handler);
        return parser;
    }

    /** 
     * See org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler javadocs 
     */
    private static class SheetHandler extends DefaultHandler {
        private SharedStringsTable sst;
        private String lastContents;
        private boolean nextIsString;

        private SheetHandler(SharedStringsTable sst) {
            this.sst = sst;
        }

        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name,
                Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
            // c => cell
            if(name.equals("c")) {
                // Print the cell reference
                System.out.print(attributes.getValue("r") + " - ");
                // Figure out if the value is an index in the SST
                String cellType = attributes.getValue("t");
                if(cellType != null && cellType.equals("s")) {
                    nextIsString = true;
                } else {
                    nextIsString = false;
                }
            }
            // Clear contents cache
            lastContents = "";
        }

        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name)
                throws SAXException {
            // Process the last contents as required.
            // Do now, as characters() may be called more than once
            if(nextIsString) {
                int idx = Integer.parseInt(lastContents);
                lastContents = new XSSFRichTextString(sst.getEntryAt(idx)).toString();
            nextIsString = false;
            }

            // v => contents of a cell
            // Output after we've seen the string contents
            if(name.equals("v")) {
                System.out.println(lastContents);
            }
        }

        public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
                throws SAXException {
            lastContents += new String(ch, start, length);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FromHowTo howto = new FromHowTo();
        howto.processOneSheet(args[0]);
        howto.processAllSheets(args[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, the line `FromHowTo howto = new FromHowTo()` is actually an error by the authors of the tutorial.  The correct line should be `ExampleEventUserModel howto = new ExampleEventUserModel()`

Comment: I'm not seeing that mistake in the docs. Well, at least not any more... ;-)